# Adapt Html component on bootstrap depending on the screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have multiple radio button when it is a big screen (and the label on the top)

and a drop down list when it's smaller

Is it possible with bootstrap to handle that case?

I think it's possible to hide the data on xs / s screen and vice versa but I don't know if it's a good idea

Comment: Did u check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities ?

Comment: well i saw that but I don't know if it is a good idea. if someone has the idea for example to resize the screen. are the data sent twice ?

Comment: Not kind of question to be done here. Its not specific for a problem that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities as D_Supreme suggested. It is a good idea.

```
    <div class"visible-lg-*">
        <span class="label label-default">New</span></h1>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>Option 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then do the following with your "small" version